# Block Validation Error

Tags: block-editor, validation

I continualy receive a block validation error in the console, but the image does not exist on my development site anywhere...

Content generated by `save` function:

```
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large"><img src="https://s.w.org/patterns/files/2021/06/Cherry-Blossom-707x1024.jpg" alt="Beautiful photomechanical prints of Cherry Blossom (1887-1897) by Ogawa Kazumasa. Original from The Rijksmuseum. " class="wp-image-524"/></figure>
```

Content retrieved from post body:

```
<figure class="wp-block-image size-large" style="font-size:14px"><img src="https://s.w.org/patterns/files/2021/06/Cherry-Blossom-707x1024.jpg" alt="Beautiful photomechanical prints of Cherry Blossom (1887-1897) by Ogawa Kazumasa. Original from The Rijksmuseum. " class="wp-image-524" /></figure>
```

Comment: Do you have any idea where the `style="font-size:14px"` came from? It doesn't seem to belong. If you attempted to edit the block code directly to add it, then that is likely what's caused your issue.